# Not getting file size in dropbox for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, dropbox

I am working on dropbox integration with iOS and I've done everything what I suppose to do, I am getting files and can download too, but I cant get file size of before download or in meta information.
Here is how I am doing in View Did Load.

```
if ([[DBSession sharedSession] isLinked]) {
    [self showProgressHud];
    [[self restClient] loadMetadata:@"/"];
}


- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient *)client loadedMetadata:(DBMetadata *)metadata {
if (metadata.isDirectory)
{
    [self hideProgessHud];
    fileList=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:0];

    for (DBMetadata *file in metadata.contents)
    {
        [fileList addObject:file];
}
}
```

getting nil response on `file.totalBytes` 
Kindly guide me how to get file size before downloading file size in dropbox 
Than,s

Comment: Why haven't you implemented `restClient:loadMetadataFailedWithError:`?

Comment: What is the relation this delegate with size this will trigger if some error occur?

Comment: This is already implemented in my code, but I only show which has concern with size

Comment: How are you checking `totalBytes`? This works for me: `NSLog(@"%lld", file.totalBytes);`. Note that size isn't returned for folders though. Also make sure you're on the latest version of [the SDK](https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/sdks/ios), currently 1.3.14.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**DBMetadata** contains information about files it contains **totalBytes** and **humanReadableSize**

```
for (DBMetadata *file in metadata.contents)
{
    NSLog(@“file size: %@”,file.humanReadableSize);
    // file.humanReadableSize contains size in NSString
    [fileList addObject:file];
}
```